# Blazor form failing validation due to items in the data model that are not shown in the form

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor (server side) project that uses a couple of EditForms. In each case the data model happens to include a nested object that is not needed in the form. I find that the form will fail validation if that object is deemed invalid, but without any explanation. Is there a way that I can examine the form's specific reason for deciding that a submit event is invalid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon, check this information [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types), about

> ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator, ValidateComplexType

When you put attribute(ValidateComplexType) on your nested objects and replace "DataAnnotationsValidator" with "ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator " you will see the error information for your nested objects, after everything in your primary edit form is valid.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. My answer will lie in examining the EditContext.

Comment: @SimonZiegler What do you mean by, "examining the EditContext"?